# What's the proper way to add space to a select element with CSS?

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-chrome, select

I am working with an existing stylesheet and I noticed that my select elements are looking pretty squished. I also noticed that when using the `normalize.css` framework this seems to happen as well:

[image: Picture.png]

I tried adding some padding to the select and the option:

[image: Picture 1.png]

It looks OK in chrome:

[image: Picture 3.png]

but still strange in firefox - notice the bloated looking arrows. It also behaves a little strange when I use sroll to select the options. Just makes me wonder if I'm doing it right.

[image: Picture 2.png]

Is this the right way to add some spacing or is there a better way? I tried using line-height as well but that didn't seem to have much effect.

Comment: I would recommend looking into the html5 boilerplate, they have an amazing reset that normalizes a lot of these common issues. (html5boilerplate.com/)

Comment: that's probably good to look at. have you check out normalize.css?

Answer (score -1):

Why not height: ?px; --Seems to work for me to get close to what I want with all browsers.